# Implementing ACS with REST + many Identity Providers - Problems - Azure

Tags: oauth, azure

I am trying to integrate ACS to use in my application's authentication system.

Currently I have a Javascript client and a WCF so I had to use a REST architecture.

I am quite puzzled on how to do this but here we go **:**

On my log-in page I managed to get a token from facebook/windows live/google and then I want to send that token to my Azure's Active Directory Namespace, I want Azure to then validate that token with facebook / windows live or whatever provider it came from and if the token is valid I want to generate an ACS Token and return it to the client so that he will have to validate all its requests with this token.

I managed to get a token using custom Service Identities created on the ACS management website, I also have a token validator. What I am missing is **how to send the facebook/windows live / google tokens to be validated against Azure.**

I found no examples that go that far other than for MVC web pages.

Is it possible to do what I want to do?